# Query to Select & check 1 row at a time & stop when it finds the right value (MYSQL)?

Tags: mysql, sql

Given this table:

```
Col1-Col2
85 - 2
95 - 4
46 - 3
79 - 6
11 - 5
13 - 1
```

The requirement is that I want the system to check each row at a time, if it see col2 =3  or col2 = 1, then it will stop & it will return the between.

Ex: when user enter "85", it will look the next record "95" (col2=4  not 3 or 1) then it will look into the next record "46" (col2=3) then it will break & return the between.

```
Col1-Col2
95 - 4
```

Ex2: when user search for "46", it will show the between of 2 boundaries (46 - 3) & (13 - 1):

```
Col1-Col2
79 - 6
11 - 5
```

I think the simplest code is to use the user defined variable in mysql, something like this:

```
select @pv:=col1, col2 from Table1 
where @pv=85
```

But this code doesn't work. I searched all over internet but couldn't find similar question.

Can anyone help me? If you can modify the query in sql fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/24b1f/3) then it will be great.

Comment: you have only these two columns in you table no other column like identity or datetime...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really should solve that with a [stored procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-procedure.html) and a [cursor](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/cursors.html).

However, it is also possible in SQL but it gets hard to read. This is for your first example

```
select col1, col2 from
(select col1, 
       col2, 
       if(col2 in (1,3) and @row = 1,@row:=@row+1, @row) as end,
       if(col1 = 85 and @row = 0,@row:=1,@row) as start       
  from Table1
  join (select @row := 0 from dual) dummy) as magic
where end = 1;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/24b1f/23